# Scrape shadow root (open) tag using Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, shadow-dom

I have to scrap a web page for the last updated date using python. A snippet of the html page is given below.

```
<dx bookmark="Save" copy="Copy URL" downvote="Vote down" edit="Edit this page" feedback="Log an issue" helpful="Is this page helpful?" locale="en" message="Contribute to this guide" lastupdate="Last Updated: {{value}}" share="Share" upvote="Vote up">

#shadow root (open)
<dx-container>
  <div data-id="bookmark" class="is-margin-bottom"></div>
  <div data-id="share" class="is-margin-bottom"><a class="copy" title="Share"><figure class="image 16x16 is-inline-block is-marginless is-margin-right"><img src="/assets/img/share.svg"></figure><span>Share</span></a></div>
  <div data-id="vote" class=""></div>
  <div data-id="updated" class="">Last Updated: June 13, 2022</div>
</dx-container>

<render slot="render"></render>

</dx>
```

Entire XPath of dx tag : /html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/dx

So far I have written the following code using Selenium :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
url = ' ' #To be read from a .txt file

driver.get(url)
def expand_shadow_element(element):
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)
  return shadow_root

root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('dx')
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)

root2 = shadow_root1.find_element_by_xpath('dx-container/div')    
print(root2)
```

I am running into the following error :

```
    root2 = shadow_root1.find_element_by_xpath('dx-container/div')        
AttributeError: 'ShadowRoot' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

Any idea on how to get the last updated date?

Answer (score -1):

You need to get the element above the shadowroot(open) which is the dx bookmark from there use shadowroot, and then xpath it. Also make sure to use driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"") as the other is depreciated. In the higher versions of selenium there is a built in function for shadow roots as well.

4.1+

```
root1=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//dx[@bookmark='Save']").shadow_root
root2=root1.find_element(By.XPATH,".//dx-container/div")
```

Other's

```
root1=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//dx[@bookmark='Save']")
shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(root1)
root2=shadow_root1.find_element(By.XPATH,".//dx-container/div")
```